# Spark Can't Read Local File

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, file-permissions, emr

I have a local file available on all Spark nodes in an EMR cluster with the following permissions:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 test_user test_group 30 Jun 21 14:20 /tmp/foo_test
```

I'm running the cluster as `ec2-user`, using the yarn scheduler.  In order for Spark/Yarn to have access to the file, I added `test_group` as a secondary group of the `yarn` user on all the nodes.

```
$ sudo -u yarn groups
  yarn hadoop test_group
```

In spark-shell, I get the following error reading the file:

```
scala> val rdd = sc.textFile("file:///tmp/foo_test")
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/foo_test (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.open(RawLocalFileSystem.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:141)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:771)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How do I read files with group-level permissions on EMR Spark?

Answer (score 0):

change permission to 770 - i.e., `chmod -R 770 /tmp` and retry.

Comment: I get the same error when the permissions of the file (across all of the nodes) are set to 770.

Comment: please try to change permission of `tmp` dir also - see updated command

Comment: It looks like /tmp already has full rwx access for user,group,other